# Unicode manipulation and garbage '[]' characters

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

I have a 4GB text file which I can't even load to view so I'm trying to separate it but I need to manipulate the data a bit at a time.

The problem is I'm getting these garbage white vertical rectangular characters and I can't search for what they are in a search engine because it won't paste nor can I get rid of them.
They look like these square parenthesis '[]' but without that small amount of space in the middle.
Their Unicode values differ so I can't just select one value and get rid of it.
I want to get rid of all of these rectangles.

Two more questions.

1) Why are there any Unicode characters here (in the img below) at all? I decoded them. What am I missing? Note: Later on I get string output that looks like a normal string such as 'code1234' etc but there are those Unicode exceptions there as well.

2) Can you see why larger `end` values would get this exception `list index out of range`? This only happens towards the end of the `range` and it isn't constant i.e. if `end` is 100 then maybe the last 5 will throw that exception but if `end` is 1000 then ONLY the LAST let's say 10 throw that exception.

Some code:

```
from itertools import islice

def read_from_file(file, start, end):
    with open(file,'rb') as f:
        for line in islice(f, start, end):
            data.append(line.strip().decode("utf-8"))
    for i in range(len(data)-1):
        try:
            if '@' in data[i]:
                a = data.pop(i)
                mail.append(a)
            else:
                print(data[i], data[i].encode())
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

data = []
mail = []
read_from_file('breachcompilationuniq.txt', 0, 10)
```

Some Output:
[Image link here as it won't let me format after pasting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Qw2.jpg)

[There's also this stuff later on, I don't know what these are either.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsB1d.jpg)

Comment: If you are opening the file as binary, you are getting bytes.  If it's text you should probably not open as binary.

Comment: I don't know the structure of the file. If I don't open it as bytes it gives an error of `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2560: character maps to <undefined>` @adr

Comment: Rectangular that you see its a placeholder for lower bytes in ASCII table  (bytes with codes from `00` to `1F` also known as non-printable characters see: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg/875px-ASCII-Table-wide.svg.png). Such symbols have no correct representation in standard fonts.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a text file which is not in the default encoding assumed by python (UTF-8), but nevertheless uses bytes values in the range 128-255.  Try:

```
f = open(file, encoding='latin_1')
content = f.read()
```

Comment: I have tried both utf-8 and latin_1 before posting and no others (if there are others), latin_1 had the same results as utf-8

Comment: It's not a pure text file if you have non-printable bytes in the stream.  Those bytes are not any form of encoding, either.  The second image contains HTML entities.

Comment: You can open and read any file with the 'latin-1' encoding, although the content may not be correct.  The same cannot be said for 'utf-8', so it is not clear what you tried exactly and why it may have failed.